# Java Math.pow() Rounding Error

Tags: java, double

I'm having trouble with (what I suspect is) a rounding error.

I have a string, `0.686357E-01`, which I'm trying to convert to a double. I've been able to split it up using the `Pattern.split()` function, and I'm capturing the base and the exponent values just fine. However, once I try to multiply them appropriately, I get this as a result: `0.06863570000000001`.

Here's my relevant code:

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("E\\+?");
String[] number = pattern.split(string);

double base = Double.parseDouble(number[0]);
int exponent = Integer.parseInt(number[1]);

number= base*Math.pow(10, exponent);
```

So, how do I avoid the rounding error? (There are ways that I can work around it, but if it's possible to do, then I'd like to know how to fix the issue)

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a rounding error. That's just how float/double behave in most programming languages. You can never have 100% percent precision dealing with floating point numbers. That's why people discourage using `(float1 == float2)` but just `abs(float1 - float2) < epsilon` instead. Precision is only guaranteed to 10^15 I believe.

Comment: Interesting - I've never experienced this behavior before. There's no way to avoid it?

Comment: @MattS First time for everything. It's actually a complicated, Numerical Analysis, [problem](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) which gives headaches to CPU architects and manufacturers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to split it, `Double.parseDouble` can handle those kinds of numbers just fine.

```
double number = Double.parseDouble("0.686357E-01");
```

[See? It works!](http://ideone.com/rkZlk)

Comment: The problem is sometimes the number actually has an exponent of "E+00" which the parser seemed to not like. Otherwise I would've done it like that.

Comment: @MattS: Hmm... that's parsing for me just fine. http://ideone.com/onONy I think your issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Interesting, I just tried it out and it did seem to be working. I must've made a mistake with something else that screwed it up before. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

0.0686357 is not exactly representable as a double-precision value.

Two solutions:

- Use e.g. `BigDecimal`.
- Limit the displayed precision to a certain number of significant figures when converting back to human-readable.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers do not have perfect precision.  If that is an issue, use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

```
String string = "0.686357E-01";
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(string);
System.out.println(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Double` will print always like that, but the value will remain correct. You'll need to format the output to get the correct value. See [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class.